# 500 Internal Server Error when using gsutil mb -l Location Constraint

Tags: google-cloud-storage

Has anyone successfully been able to create a location specific storage bucket? I am unable to do so for granular US regions like US-CENTRAL1. Attempting to do so results in a 500 Internal Server Error. I'm using the latest version of `gsutil`:

`> gsutil mb -l US-CENTRAL1 gs://somebucketname => 
Failure: BotoServerError: 500 Internal Server Error; Code: InternalError; Message: We encountered an internal error. Please try again.`

Answer (score 2):

As the [regional buckets documentation](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/regional-buckets#_How) says, only Durable Reduced Availability storage is available for regional buckets. To specify DRA when creating the bucket:

```
gsutil mb -c DRA -l US-CENTRAL1 gs://some-bucket
```

I'll also open a ticket to provide a more informative response in this case instead of returning an HTTP 500.