# How to create GS Bucket in other locations than EU and US?

Tags: google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-endpoints

I am writing sample code to create Bucket in Google Cloud Storage. I am following this XML API written at [link](https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/concepts-techniques#specifyinglocations) -

```
PUT / HTTP/1.1
Host: helloworld.storage.googleapis.com
Accept-Encoding: identity
Date: Fri, 01 Apr 2011 21:52:39 GMT
Content-Length: 92
x-goog-api-version: 2
x-goog-project-id: 123456789123
Authorization: Bearer 1/zVNpoQNsOSxZKqOZgckhpQ

<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreateBucketConfiguration>
  <LocationConstraint>EU</LocationConstraint>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

Google Storage Locations -

```
EU - European Union
US - United States
US-EAST1 - Eastern United States
US-EAST2 - Eastern United States
US-EAST3 - Eastern United States
US-CENTRAL1 - Central United States
US-CENTRAL2 - Central United States
US-WEST1 - Western United States
```

I am able to create Bucket if I am providing US and EU in `<LocationConstraint>` tag. But if I am giving any other than these two, let say - US-CENTRAL2 in `<LocationConstraint>` tag as -

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreateBucketConfiguration>
   <LocationConstraint>US-CENTRAL2</LocationConstraint>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

Then on create bucket this code is throwing error that -

```
Encountered too many Internal Server errors (6), aborting request. PUT '/mybucket/' on Host 'commondatastorage.googleapis.com' @ 'Fri, 16 Aug 2013 09:08:21 GMT' -- ResponseCode: 500, ResponseStatus: Internal Server Error
```

How can I create bucket in rest six section other than US and EU locations?? Is there any changes in API??

Thanks for the help,

Neelam Sharma

Comment: please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17835505/500-internal-server-error-when-using-gsutil-mb-l-location-constraint

Comment: @MikeSchwartz Thanks Mike, I also have tried by adding one more tag <StorageClass> with value DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY and providing these locations in <LocationConstraint> solve my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For creating Buckets in other locations than US and EU, we need to send request of PUT Bucket by adding one more tag  `<StorageClass>` with value DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY as -

```
<xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<CreateBucketConfiguration>
   <LocationConstraint>US-CENTRAL2</LocationConstraint>
   <StorageClass>DURABLE_REDUCED_AVAILABILITY</StorageClass>
</CreateBucketConfiguration>
```

Adding this tag solved my problem.

Comment: Just to make it more explicit, regional buckets are only supported for DRA storage, as also noted here: https://developers.google.com/storage/docs/regional-buckets